# Regular (polygonal) tiling using R

Tags: r, polygon

I am trying to come up with a script which creates a matrix that contains coordinates of adjacent polygons of a regular polygonal tiling, e.g. squares and octagons with a little space inserted between them (space not shown in picture: there, polygons share edges).

[image]

My first try was to "walk" through the coordinate system from a starting point. It gets complicated though when I walk through the first column of the tiling, e.g. upwards and now have to walk downwards to create the second column. Either I drop the approach completely or I come up with a better sequential scheme. Can you help?

```
ID = 1 # not relevant here
p=c(0,0) # starting point
l_m=10 # length of an edge
NODES <- matrix(NA,nrow=0,ncol = 3) 
calculateSquareUp <- function(p_start,l_m) { # draws the points of a square while walking upwards, counterclockwise
  p1=p_start
  p2=p1+c(l_m,0)
  p3=p2+c(0,l_m)
  p4=p3+c(-l_m,0)
  NODES <- rbind(p1,p2,p3,p4)
  NODES <- cbind(ID,NODES)
  list("p_up"=p4,"p_down"=p2,"NODES"=NODES)
}

calculateOctagonUp <- function(p_start,l_m) { # draws the points of an octagon while walking upwards, counterclockwise
  p1=p_start
  p2=p1+c(l_m,0)
  p3=p2+c(l_m,l_m)/sqrt(2)
  p4=p3+c(0,l_m)
  p5=p4+c(-l_m,l_m)/sqrt(2)
  p6=p5+c(-l_m,0)
  p7=p6-c(l_m,l_m)/sqrt(2)
  p8=p7+c(0,-l_m)
  NODES <- rbind(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8)
  NODES <- cbind(ID,NODES)
  list("p_up"=p6,"p_down"=p4,"NODES"=NODES)
}

calculateSquareDown <- function(p_start,l_m) { # draws the points of a square while walking downwards, counterclockwise
  p1=p_start
  p2=p1+c(l_m,0)
  p3=p2+c(0,-l_m)
  p4=p3+c(-l_m,0)
  NODES <- rbind(p1,p2,p3,p4)
  NODES <- cbind(ID,NODES)
  list("p_up"=p2, "p_down"=p2,"NODES"=NODES)
}

calculateOctagonDown <- function(p_start,l_m) { # draws the points of an octagon while walking downwards, counterclockwise
  p1=p_start
  p2=p1+c(l_m,0)
  p3=p2+c(l_m,-l_m)/sqrt(2)
  p4=p3+c(0,-l_m)
  p5=p4+c(-l_m,-l_m)/sqrt(2)
  p6=p5+c(-l_m,0)
  p7=p6-c(-l_m,l_m)/sqrt(2)
  p8=p7+c(0,l_m)
  NODES <- rbind(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8)
  NODES <- cbind(ID,NODES)
  list("p_up"=p3,"p_down"=p6, "NODES"=NODES)
}


space=c(10,10) 
# Easy example: a 2x2 tiling
max_polygons=2 # per column
n_polygons=4 # total number of polygons
NODES <- matrix(NA,nrow=0,ncol = 3) 
for (i in 1:n_polygons){
    if(i < round(n_polygons/2,0)){ # if first column, walk upwards
        for (j in 1:max_polygons) {
          if (j%%2==0){
            listOctagon = calculateOctagonUp(p_start=p,l_m=l_m)
            p = listOctagon[[1]]+space
            NODES <-rbind(NODES,listOctagon[[3]])
          }
          else {
            listSquare = calculateSquareUp(p_start=p,l_m=l_m)
            p = listSquare[[1]]+space
            NODES <-rbind(NODES,listSquare[[3]])

          }
        }
    } else if(i >round(n_polygons/2,0)){ # if second column, walk downwards
        for (j in 1:max_polygons) {
          if (j%%2==0){
            listOctagon = calculateOctagonDown(p_start=p,l_m=l_m)
            p = listOctagon[[2]]+space
            NODES <-rbind(NODES,listOctagon[[3]])
          }
          else {
            listSquare = calculateSquareDown(p_start=p,l_m=l_m)
            p = listSquare[[2]]+space
            NODES <-rbind(NODES,listSquare[[3]])

          }
        }
    }
}


plot(NODES[,2],NODES[,3], type = "p")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is at least most of the way toward a solution with `sf`. Here we take advantage of the affine transformation capability of the package, and simply duplicate a tile composed on one octagon and one square as much as we want. I borrowed and modified your octagon function to make a quick octagon. Obviously this is going to create a slanted grid as shown, but some modification to the plot function can tessellate the unit in whatever direction you want. The key is just to specify the right translation for the next tile by adding `c(x, y)` to your `sfc` object.

For some background, `sf` stores points and lines as 2-column matrices, and polygons as lists of matrices. This is why there is a call to `list` inside `st_polygon`.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.2.0, proj.4 4.9.3
square <- st_polygon(
  list(
    matrix(c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  )
)
calculateOctagonUp <- function(p_start,l_m) { # draws the points of an octagon while walking upwards, counterclockwise
  p1=p_start
  p2=p1+c(l_m,0)
  p3=p2+c(l_m,l_m)/sqrt(2)
  p4=p3+c(0,l_m)
  p5=p4+c(-l_m,l_m)/sqrt(2)
  p6=p5+c(-l_m,0)
  p7=p6-c(l_m,l_m)/sqrt(2)
  p8=p7+c(0,-l_m)
  rbind(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p1)
}

octagon <- st_polygon(list(calculateOctagonUp(c(0,1), 1)))

unit <- st_sfc(square, octagon)
plot_grid <- function(tile, nrow, ncol){
  col <- tile
  for (i in 1:nrow){
    col <- c(col, col + c(0, 2 + sqrt(2)))
  }
  grid <- col
  for (i in 1:ncol){
    grid <- c(grid, grid + c(1 + sqrt(2) / 2, -(1 + sqrt(2) / 2)))
  }
  plot(grid)
}

plot_grid(unit, 3, 3)
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-22 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).